# Exec - run two commands

Tags: bash, exec

I use Debian with [**LXDE**](http://lxde.org).

I have a simple bash script that runs

```
lxterminal -e /home/userpc/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend | sleep 5 | xbmc
```

The script works well. These three commands I want to add to the activator on the desktop, and the script to remove. Activator looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=lxterminal -e /home/userpc/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend | sleep 5 | xbmc
Name=test
Icon=brak
```

The problem is that exec does not want to run these commands:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e /home/userpc/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend  | sleep 5 | xbmc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt really be piping these commands. Perhaps something like this

```
Exec='lxterminal -e /home/userpc/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend; sleep 5; xbmc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may actually want to separate the commands with the double-ampersand `&&` operator.

```
Exec='lxterminal -e /home/userpc/tvheadend/build.linux/tvheadend && sleep 5 && xbmc'
```

That will "fail-fast": if any of the commands fails (exits with an error code), subsequent commands will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Only the following solution works in my case (enclosed in backticks):

```
Exec=`exo-open --launch WebBrowser https://www.example.com; sleep 2 & exo-open --launch WebBrowser https://www.example.com/`
```

*Debian 10/Xfce4*